# Expressions of elements of $[FG, FG]$ for group algebra $FG$ of a finite group $G$ over a field $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $S=[FG,FG]$ be the vector subspace of $FG$ spanned by all commutators $xy-yx$ of elements $x,y$ of $G$, where $FG$ is the group algebra of a finite group $G$ over a field $F$ with ${\rm char}~F$ not a divisior of $|G|$, let
$$s=\sum_{a,b\in G}\lambda_{ab}(ab-ba).$$
Then setting $x=ab, y=a$, we have
$$s=\sum_{x,y\in G}\lambda_{xy}(x-y^{-1}xy)~?$$
I have no idea for this problem, may someone give me a note? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the double subscript confuses you, that's not a product, and $\lambda_{x,y}$ should rather be named $\mu_{x,y}$ and it's equal to $\lambda_{y,y^{-1}x}$.

Comment: @Berci, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$\sum \lambda_{a,b}(ab-ba)=\sum \lambda_{a,b}(ab-a^{-1}(ab)a)$

Comment: Thank you very much!